# Nodemailer not sending the mail to the address i specify

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I'm trying to send a mail to an email address with nodemailer + mailtrap, but i'm receving the mail in the mailtrap account... why is this happening?

here's my code:

```
const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: "smtp.mailtrap.io",
  port: 2525,
  auth: {
    user: "79a422a4c8485b",
    pass: "492900f98e999e",
  },
}); 


app.get("/sendMail", function (req, res) {
  const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 54);
  const link = `http://localhost:5000/verify?id=${rand}`;
  const mailOptions = {
    from: "sender@server.com",
    to: req.query.to, // DESTINY MAIL, BUT NO MATTER WHAT I PUT IN HERE, I ONLY RECEIVE THE MAIL 
    // ON THE MAILTRAP ACCOUNT!
    subject: "Hello ✔",
    text: "Hello world ✔",
    html: `Hello,<br> Please Click on the link to verify your email.<br><a href=${link}>Click here to verify</a>`,
  };

  console.log(mailOptions);
  // smtpTransport.sendMail();
  transport.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error: any, response: any) {
    if (error) {
      console.log("no se pudo mandar el mail porque ->", error);
      res.end("error");
    } else {
      console.log("response", response);
      console.log(`Message sent: ${response.message}`);
      res.send("done");
    }
  });
});
```

What am i doing wrong?